# NPM: Can general npm binary dependencies be built statically?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, nodejs-server

This question is about server-only applications.

Is there any ability to build statically dependencies that are usually building from sources when we install them via `npm install`? Some params or flags maybe?

I want to get `node_modules` that are independent from system libraries (except something very basic like glibc) and can be moved to other hosts where there are no custom dependencies.

Comment: What I usually do is to containerize the app with docker. I build and run this image with docker compose.

Comment: Yes, Docker is an option. But I want to go another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: No. If a library require a build process, you can't skip it with a flag or param of npm.

You can download the library, understand the build process, build the binary for each of your required environments, make some adjustments to the code so it will use the pre built binaries, upload it as a new npm package (in case the original library license allow that), and you are good to go...